# JPA: merge entity with existing id

Tags: java, jpa

I am working on a web application with JPA 2.0, and I open and close the EntityManager on each request. The user can create a new entity and also set the id-field (the field has a meaning and I cannot change the table structure). To store the new entity I have to use the "merge"-method of the EntityManager, but when there is already an existing entity with the same id it just gets updated.
Do I have to check manually if there is already an entity with the same id, or can this be done in better way? Or is there something else wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why do you “have to use the "merge"-method”? What do you want to do if the entity already exists?

Comment: I cannot use persist because my entities are detached since I create (and close) my entitymanager instance on each request. I want to prevent the user from updating an existing entity when he actually wanted to create a new one.

Comment: I dont't have to user merge, I can use persist - somehow I thought I could not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `persist` method, an `EntityPersistsException` will be thrown for duplicated ids.

That said, from an user point of view, the sooner he know an ID is already used, the better (optimally, when the field is updated check it with ajax).

Comment: I cannot use persist because I create my entitymanager instance on each request. E.g. at the first request I read entities to display in a table, at the second request I store a newly created entity.

Comment: Create a new object for each request. If I understood correctly, you are just adding new entities and do not want to persist changes done to entities already in the database. Don't use a detached entity as the object where to store the new values.

Comment: I have not much experience with JPA, but afaik I have to use merge to attach an entity (what I am already doing). Maybe you can clarify a bit?

Comment: Thank you, I thought that doesn't work, but I must have had other problems, it works!